# Is there any standard solution for Blueprint structure to be fetched, for all publications in a CMS?

Tags: web8.5, templating, blueprint, c#, tbb

For our Web 8.5 implementation, we have a requirement to fetch the complete Blueprint structure using C# TBB's. We do have an implementation that uses Metadata Schemas to fetch the Publication details and ascertain whether its a child or a parent and get the structure. However, the metadata field is NOT available for all publications, as they belong to different websites. Is it possible to do it in any other way? As in by directly reading the 'Blueprint Hierarchy' maybe for every publication?

**UPDATE:**
I now would like to pass the data as a JSON in my TBB. However, JSON for mat is NOT available in the 'ContentType'. Refer Image below. Is there anything I misunderstood?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly, take a look at the `BluePrintNodesFilter` filter in the TOM.NET API (chm).

> BluePrintNodesFilter Class
>
> Represents the Filter for a list of  BluePrint nodes

Example usage:

```
SystemManager systemManager = session.SystemManager;
BluePrintNodesFilter filter = new BluePrintNodesFilter(session);
IEnumerable<BluePrintNode> allBlueprintNodes = systemManager.GetBluePrintNodes(filter);
```

Alternatively, you can use the `GetListBluePrintNodes()`

Comment: Thank you. I now have a new issue, NOT sure if I misunderstood something. Updated my query with the details.

Comment: It almost goes without saying, but this is an expensive query. So make sure you don't do it often.

Comment: @NewUser Please stick to one question per post. That way, anyone experiencing the same issue in the future will be able to easily find it and any answers. Otherwise, you end up with a lot of irrelevant information in a post.